# Javascript: How to call a function from multiple prototypes?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, prototype-programming

Good day,

I'm coding with phaser 3 and javascript then tried doing classes like so:

```js
class gameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
create()
  {
    // add inputs
    this.cursors = this.setDirectional('W', 'A', 'S', 'D');
  }
}
```

I tried doing prototypes by adding

```js
gameScene.prototype = {
  setDirectional:
    function (setUp, setDown, setLeft, setRight) {
      // some code
    })
  },

  someOtherMethod:
    function(){
       // some other code
    }
}
```

but it produces a 'not a function' error for setDirectional() function. It seems to work when I seperate the prototypes:

```js
gameScene.prototype.setDirectional =  function (setUp, setDown, setLeft, setRight){ 
    // code 
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Is there a workaround to call the setDirectional() function from within the class while using the grouped prototype format?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe doing it like `gameScene.prototype.setDirectional = function (setUp, setDown, setLeft, setRight) {}` would help

Comment: Thank you for answering @DominikMatis. Although that is working in my code but I was hoping there is a way for me to add multiple functions in a single gameScene.prototype code.

also sorry i think i missed the parameters on the 3rd snippet

Comment: when you do `gameScene.prototype = { }` you are simply overriding default prototype and that's not correct, what I did is what you want, I add this function, when you need multiple, you need to do it one by one

Comment: Sorry for asking further questions. So if i need another function say otherMethod() it should be like this: `gameScene.prototype.setDirectional = function(){  // code } ;
gameScene.protoype.otherMethod = function(){ //code};` ?

Comment: Exactly, this is my solution

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be good now. I also appreciate the prototypes explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning `object` to `Class.prototype` cannot be the correct behavior. However, you can add a new property to `Class.prototype` and store your methods here.

```
class gameScene {
  create() {
    return "create function"
  }
}

gameScene.prototype.methods = {
    setDirectional: function(){
        return "test"
    }
}

console.log(gameScene.prototype.methods.setDirectional())
```